# JQuery validate disable button until all fields are active, but it should not show error on every key press

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p628Y/1/)

**Here is the html**

```
<form action='includes/pgd_cc.php' METHOD='POST' id="ccSelectForm">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><strong>Email Address</strong>

        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="inputEmail" placeholder="jane.smith@email.com" id="inputEmail" />
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmailConfirm"><strong>Confirm Email Address</strong>

        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="inputEmailConfirm" placeholder="jane.smith@email.com" id="inputEmailConfirm" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="emailSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click me to buy">Credit Card Checkout &raquo;</button>
```

**Here is the script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ccSelectForm').validate({
        rules: {
            inputEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            inputEmailConfirm: {
                equalTo: '#inputEmail'
            }
        }
    });

    $('#ccSelectForm input').on('keyup blur', function () {
        if ($('#ccSelectForm').valid()) {
            $('button.btn').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('button.btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });

});
```

As i am doing

```
    $('#ccSelectForm input').on('keyup blur', function () {
        if ($('#ccSelectForm').valid()) {
            $('button.btn').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('button.btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```

My Form is always getting validated and showing errors.

I don't want to show the errors in the form while the user type a single word itself.

I want to show errors only after going to next field and it should only validate the current field is typed.

How can i alter this code to achieve this..

Comment: Can't you use a simple jQuery based validation plugin?

Comment: You mean to write custom one ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I believe i used the basic one, May i know what you mean pls

Comment: Just use blur event not keyup. So it will be validated only after the focus moves to next input only.

Comment: @AnilPanwar You mean like this ? `$('#emailSubmit').on('keyup', function () {` ?

Comment: Ya but instead of keyup use blur and on blur of inputs not submit.

Comment: @AnilPanwar blur of inputs means ?

Comment: @AnilPanwar Like this $('input').on('blur', function() { ? – Biz Dev B 12 mins ago

Comment: $("#inputEmail ,#inputEmailConfirm").on("blur", function (){ If ($("#inputEmail").val().length == $("#inputEmqilConfirm"). val().length) { If($("#inputEmail").val()!= $("#inputEmailConfirm") { alert("Email not same"); } else{ alert("Email not same"); } }); meanwhile you can remove attribute disable if both email matched in the condition by removeAttr method of jquery

Answer (score 1):

It is better to bind it to the `submit`. So that, it validates everything only once, and not every time for every input, when the `keyup` is fired. Try this:

```
$('#emailSubmit').on('click', function () {
  return $('#ccSelectForm').valid();
});
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/valiwetese**

Comment: Thanks, but the submit is not enabled after the form is valid

Comment: @BizDevB Oh yeah, well, lemme figure out a different way. Let's not disable the `Submit`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I have a doubt.. We are disabling the button, then how can we identify the click function of it !

Comment: @BizDevB We are not disabling it now. `:)`

Comment: Is it possible to disable the button initially and then enable it after the form is valid ?

Comment: @BizDevB The checking happens in the click event of the submit button. So... `:)`

Comment: So, we can't do it ? :(

Comment: Just `return $('#ccSelectForm').valid();` is enough in handler